# SQL group by retorna duplicado POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Minha *query SQL* está retornando multiplas *rows* com o mesmo id segue:

```
SELECT distinct (c.nome), c.id, c.email,c.telefone1,c.telefone2,
  SUM(a.valor) AS "valorDaCompra",u.id AS  "idLoja",u.nome AS  "nomeLoja", 
  SUM(a.qtd_pecas) AS "qtdPecasCompradas", a.data_hora as "dataHora",
  c.data_hora as "dataCadastro" 
FROM cliente as c
INNER JOIN atendimento AS a 
  ON a.id_cliente = c.id INNER JOIN usuario AS u
  ON a.id_loja = u.id 
WHERE a.id_empresa= 843
  AND a.id_loja IN (2855) 
  AND a.venda = true 
GROUP BY a.data_hora, c.id,a.id_cliente,u.id,c.data_hora 
HAVING SUM(a.valor) >= 2 AND SUM(a.valor) <= 20000
ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

[image: Resultado da query trazendo resultado duplicado]

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço a estrutura das suas tabelas, o que dificulta um pouco a análise mas, revise os seguintes pontos:

1. Relacionamento **a.id_loja = u.id.**. Um usuário é uma loja ? Se a resposta for não. Seu relacionamento ta errado.
2. Existem agregações na sua query **SUM(a.valor) e SUM(a.qtd_pecas)**. A regra é que todos os outros campos sejam informados no GROUP BY. Ficando dessa forma: 
   **GROUP BY c.nome, c.id, c.email, c.telefone1, c.telefone2, u.id, u.nome, a.data_hora, c.data_hora**. Nesse caso, o **destinct** não é necessário.
3. É provável que o nome do cliente apareça varias vezes, se ele tiver comprado em dias e horários diferentes **(a.data_hora)**.

Comment: O que acontece é isso, a 3 opção da questão da a.data_hora, o cliente quando compra em datas diferentes duplica.

Comment: E sim o usuario é uma loja. Como eu posso fazer para o cliente não ficar duplicado?

Comment: Remove a coluna  **(a.data_hora)** da sua consulta. Dessa forma a o cliente deixa de aparecer mais de uma vez e valor da sua compra é somado desconsiderando a data da compra.

Comment: Conseguir aqui, foi só colocar max(a.data_hora) que ele retorna corretamente

Comment: Boa!.. só tem q ter em mente q essa data e hora que vai aparecer é a da ultima compra, mas que o valor e a quantidade são de todas juntas.

Comment: Essa é a intenção mesmo, vlw jow